# Prawn Adding new line in table

Tags: prawn

I have the following code to build PDF document with Prawn:

```
items = [["PERIOD","EMPLOYEE", "EMPLOYEE NAME", "HOURS", "FTES"]]

items += @mandates.each.map do |mandate|

[
    mandate[:fte_period_end_date],
    mandate[:fte_employee_id],
    strname,
    mandate[:fte_sum_of_hours],
    mandate[:fte_sum_of_ftes],
]
end
```

@mandates is sorted by fte_employee_id and fte_by period_end_date

I want to insert totals lines per employe for fte_sum_of_hours and fte_sum_of_ftes when pass throw next employee.

What command permits me to insert these lines with Prawn?

Comment: I believe @mandates has no bearing on the question you're asking. Are we to assume you're attempting to build a table? If so, what does the rest of your code look like?

Answer (score 0):

Pass them in the array that you are displaying the total from - in Ruby, calculate for each section of elements, the total. Don't do the work in Prawn (it's not Excel).

```
data = [["product 1: ","$10.00"],["product 2: ", "$20.00"],["Subtotal:","$30.00]]
```

For example. Then you can format the table with consideration to row 3, the subtotal, with cell styles.